# What does compilerOptions.target specify in tsconfig.json?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So as of mid-2016 just about all the Angular2 TypeScript tutorials and examples use `"target": "es5"` in the `compilerOptions` section of the `tsconfig.json` file.

I also see people saying that setting `"target": "es6"` makes a lot of their errors/problems go away.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    ...
  }
}
```

But what exactly is this specifying? Is this telling the TypeScript compiler what version of ECMAScript to generate?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it sets the target version to ES6. Check the following out:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html